# An "optimal" algorithm for cleaning up object storage

Tags: javascript, sql, algorithm, amazon-s3

I have a portal where customers save user-generated content, including images. Whenever a new image is uploaded to my portal, I save the image file in S3 object storage [bucket] and persist a reference to this file in my database. This works fine.

From time to time, customers replace previously save images with newer/different versions. I again save the image in the same bucket, and update the database record to reference the new version.

This results many orphaned images - ones that are no longer used anywhere, yet still exist in the object storage. I want to delete those images, since those are no longer used anywhere.

The naive version would be:

```
  const query = `
    SELECT
      row_to_json(s)
    FROM (
      SELECT
        filename
      FROM
        items
    ) s
  `;
  const result = await server.pg.query(query);
  const items = result.rows.map((j) => j.row_to_json);
  const allFiles = getS3Files();
  for (let i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
    if (!items.contains(allFiles[i])) {
      await unlink(allFiles[i]);
    }
  }
```

This however would be a very expensive and a slow way of purging my object storage.

Any ideas how this could be optimized?

Comment: Why not have users upload using the same key as the existing object so that when items are updated, there are no orphans?

Comment: Thank you for considering my ask. In theory what you are recommending is possible. We would need to have a temp file on the storage side, then whenever changes are saved by customers, we could immediately rename to the permanent name constructed in a way that would alleviate the problem.

Following your advice would however require a somewhat significant effort migrating...

Comment: Ok, then couldn't whatever process is updating the database with the new filenames store the old ones in a table of items to be removed (or just do the removal itself)?  At the end of the day, without some change to how the database is updated, you necessarily need to do a complete set to set comparison, and with two unbounded sets, it will be O(n) at best, and get expensive eventually.

Comment: I would say, kind of, yes and no. Your statement is accurate, but perhaps we could do filtering in the database. Say we get a partial list of files in the bucket, and have the query return us ones that are not referenced? It would not purge all resources that are no longer referenced. However, it would return a list of files that good to delete. Eventually, we would get all files...

Comment: That would still compare a set to a set, just doing the work in the database.  Unless you have an index on the filenames there, it's still going to be computationally expensive (even with an index, it's still not ideal).  And you'd still have to routinely do the entire sweep of files, since any file could be orphaned, at least as I understand the situation.

Comment: How many files are we talking about? S3 supports batch requests for both listing and deleting objects in chunks of 1000. That  should be fast enough unless you have millions of files.

Comment: @AnonCoward I don't think that `JOIN` is really expensive, we long as the set is not too large. Like you suggest, indexing will further improve the performance. We would need to constantly/periodically run jobs. Depending on the percentage of orphaned files, we could pick pace or throttle down.

Comment: @gog batching is a great idea. Thank you. It would improve the delete. We could build an array of files before unlinking. However, there is still a problem with getting a list of files. This list will grow very long overtime, and we would need to use paging to pull all filenames. This will, at some point, become very expensive. I would like to avoid this problem more than anything else. Still, a great recommendation as far as sending delete request for multiple keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't detect orphaned files when you create them, then you need a garbage collection process.

This is basically the procedure you outlined, except that you can do it incrementally.  Each round of garbage collection would work like this.

1. Remember the time when the round starts;
2. Scan filenames in items, in some arbitrary order.  Each file you discover is *used*.  When you discover it, remember the time as its "last-used" time.
3. Scan the files in S3, in arbitrary order, deleting any file with a "last-used" time earlier than the round start, and a "create time" earlier than the round start

When you're finished scanning S3, you can start a new round.

As I mentioned, you do this *incrementally*.  Every time you add a file, you either scan 4 filenames in `items`, or 4 files in S3, depending on what phase of the process you are in.

Additionally, whenever you modify `items`, mark them used so that they can't be deleted in the current round.

Running the garbage collection process incrementally at this rate will ensure that at most two thirds of the files in S3 are orphaned at any time.